# Is there any way I can use free gpu (like colab, kaggle..) to run my local repository?

Tags: machine-learning, gpu, artificial-intelligence, google-colaboratory, training-data

when I train a model usually we do the following steps:
we create a new notebook on colab and somehow upload the repository there( either git clone or uploading the repo) and after training we download the model.

Can we somehow do the training part in my local computer just only using the gpu from colab or any other platform?

Is there any way to do that without uploading the files after each change again and again?

Comment: This would be extremely slow as the data has to be transferred over the internet to reach the GPU.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jupyter hub to do that part locally. It will use your local resources (CPU or GPU). And works same as colab, but it doesn't need to upload data there all the time like colab.
Or you can have a GCP instance which gives you jupyter lab and GPU. So it's much easier than using colab all the time. (You have to pay for GPU there)